# How can i use buttons from a Fragment in the FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity and 2 Fragments to create a ViewPager, and I want to open a different Activity and passing data to the Activity when clickling on a button on the first Fragment, but since the Fragment is not an activity i cant use this :

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(this, PickAppLine.class);
                    intent.putExtra("key", MyData);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

So I thought i could just do it on the FragmentActivity, but when im using buttons from the layout of the Fragment Im getting nullpointerexception, so Is there a way I could use the button from the Frgament layout on the FragmentActivity(with a different layout)? or is there a way to pass data between a Fragment to another Activity?

Thank You!

Comment: You have done some searching for fragments, haven't you ?

Comment: you could just replace `this` with `this.getActivity()` and it would work...

Comment: also, please check how `MainActivity` and `FirstFragment` communicate in this example: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default

Comment: Cool,worked, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

go in this link

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

the short way:

```
public class MainActivity extends fragmentActivity{
   ....

   public void performClick(){
    ....
   }

}


public MyFragment extends Fragment{
  ...
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == button.getId()){
       ((MainActivity)getActivity()).performClick();
    }
  }

}
```

when the button in the fragment in clicked the performClick() function is called in the MainActivity.

Comment: That seems really good, will it work if i create a different class for the Fragment? or must I do it in the same class of the FargmentActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalBroadcastManager.

In your Fragment when the button is clicked do the following.

```
Intent intent = new Intent( "button_pressed_action" );
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance( getActivity() ).sendBroadcast( intent );
```

In your Activity you need to register a broadcast receiver to pick it up.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context ctxt, Intent intent ) {
         if ( intent.getAction().equals("button_pressed_action") {
               // Handle the button press as you wish.
         }
    }
}
```

Then in your activity's onCreate or onCreateView methods you register the receiver. Your best creating the Receiver as a global variable so you deregister it onDestroy.

```
private MyReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle bundle ) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mm_map_frag, group, false);
    mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver( mReceiver, new IntentFilter("button_pressed_action");
    return v;
}
```

Make sure you deregister the receiver at a suitable time. Usually in the activity's onDestroy method.

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // when its destroyed we may need to go through and unregister all of the enabled receivers.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance( getActivity() ).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        mReceiver = null;

    }
```

Comment: Did He ask for BroadcastManager ?

Comment: isnt there a simpeler way? cant I implement the OnClickListener on the FragmentActivity and use a button from the Fragment? Ill edit the post and show you waht I tried

Comment: There is a simpler way I thought you wanted to know how to use intents to to do it. Sorry

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper he was using Intents and to use Intents in this way LocalBroadcastManager would be how you did it.

Comment: The way ilan or  Zhuinden suggested.

Comment: I don't think you get what I'm saying. I thought the original question wanted to know how to do it using Intents (my fault for not reading thoroughly). I realise this is not the best way nor the only way but it is how you could do it using Intents.

Comment: For a beginner your post looks some what overloaded :) Happy Coding